# Running nginx as a non-root user on Dockerfile

Tags: nginx, permissions, bash, docker

I have created the following Dockerfile to use a non-root user for my Nginx service. However, when I ran the docker image that I have created and look at my docker logs i get the following error.

```
2020-10-14T11:52:04.831656127Z nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020-10-14T11:52:04.831687644Z 2020/10/14 11:52:04 [warn] 1#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2020-10-14T11:52:04.832768412Z 2020/10/14 11:52:04 [emerg] 1#0: mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi8-minimal
USER root 
RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps shadow-utils net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash proxy

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/ 

RUN chown proxy /var/log/nginx
RUN chown proxy /var/lib/nginx/ 

USER proxy 
WORKDIR /home/proxy

#COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN chmod 755 /home/proxy
#To start up NGINX 
EXPOSE 80
USER proxy
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: In your Dockerfile add directive to create /var/log/nginx and /var/lib/nginx/ and change owner of this both directoriess to the user which will start nginx process.

Comment: hi thanks for your response, how would i change the owner of the directories to the new user in the dockerfile?

Comment: Before "USER proxy" line use RUN with `mkdir -p` (twice) to create directories and then RUN (twice too) with `chown` to change the owner.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me: i have tried what you have suggested and it seems to have fixed those errors. When i build the Dockerfile i get the: 2020-10-15T14:53:59.110212487Z nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2020-10-15T14:53:59.119494037Z nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)